# how to assign an open graph object to a user

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

If I have an article with all the og: meta tags, how do I assign the object to a user, so that when other people like it, the feed will read "X action Y's object" for instance "Peter liked Jaspers article", how can I enter Jasper's facebook id in an og: meta tag to associate the og:object with him?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible. The story that is generated when someone likes something is a standard format, managed by facebook. If you have a full like story configured in your og tags, maybe you could just name the author/owner in the description or something? I don't think you can link in them though.